# How to filter records from expand.grid function?

Tags: r

I have a dataset:

```
set.seed(1234)
data = list(A=sort(sample(10:30,2,F)), B=sort(sample(40:60,2,F)), 
            D=sort(sample(60:80,2,F)), E=sort(sample(100:200,2,F)))
```

Using this dataset I want to create a dataset of all combinations which can provide required total.

Here is my code:

```
combins = expand.grid(data)
combins$total = rowSums(combins)
```

If I use the script above, it is creating all combinations. But I need combination which can make required total.

In "combins", I want to keep combinations which can give "total"=250.
See the 7th record. I want to keep only that record.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you just want `combins[combins$total == 250, ]`?

Comment: I don't want to do it separately. While creating those combinations, it should keep only those combinations.